# PHP bug - IF statement made insert run twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

*Hello all this is my frist post so thanks for all the help learning PHP and SQL*

I have 3 pages but I think the only page you need would be **Page 2** that is where the problem is but I add all 3 if I am wrong

**Page 1 html form**

```
<form method="POST" action="profile_image_getdata.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myimage">
 <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Page 2 profile_image_getdata.php (badly name)**

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once( "db/db_connection.php" );
require_once( "functions/page_control_func.php" );
require_once( "error/error_set.php" );

if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] === 'POST' ) {
    $S_id = $_SESSION[ "id" ];

    $imagename = $_FILES[ "myimage" ][ "name" ];

    //Get the content of the image and then add slashes to it 
    $imagetmp = addslashes( file_get_contents( $_FILES[ 'myimage' ][ 'tmp_name' ] ) );

    //Insert the image name and image content in image_table
    $sql_i = "INSERT INTO image_table_test (`image_ID`, `id`, `name`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '$S_id', '$imagename', '$imagetmp');";

    /*mysqli_query($insert_image);*/
    $result_i = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i );

    if ( mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i ) ) { //  <----This was my bug
    //if ( $result_i ) { // <----this is my fix
        redirect_to( "profile_image_fetch_image.php?id=$S_id" );
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_i . "<br>" . mysqli_error( $conn );
    }
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** 
in the above if copied will insert 2 times into the database. I have 2 lines of code, one is the bug and the other the fix. But I would like to understand why would this line of code:

```
//if ( mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i ) ) { //  <----This was my bug
```

would make my code loop, run twice or to insert into the data base 2 times.
the fix was to replace that line of code use the variable so:

```
if ( $result_i ) { // <----this is my fix
```

It took me a while to find because I was looking for something that runs more than once, not an IF statement.

If the answer is "I don't no know it's a bug." I complete understand but if there is an answer out there I would like to understand how can any IF statement make something run more than once? I thought IF statement will use code if it is TRUE and not if it is FALSE. Not run loops.

*And so you have the full picture here is the last page*

**Page 3 profile_image_fetch_image.php**

```
<?php
header("content-type:image/jpeg");
session_start();
require_once("db/db_connection.php");

if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] === 'GET' ) {
    $G_id = $_GET[ 'id' ];

    $sql_S = "SELECT * FROM image_table_test WHERE ID = $G_id;";
    $result_S = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_S );
    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result_S ) > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result_S ) ) {
            $image_name = $row[ "name" ];
            $image_content = $row[ "image" ];
            echo $image_content;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are simply using two tim  the   mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_S ).. each time you use this function  you perform/execute the query  ..

Comment: I see so even if it is in an if statement it can still run the function. So my missup is like setting a variable in an if statement by using one = and not using == or ===.... if(a=b){

Answer (score 2):

You called the function twice so it is normal that the insert was run twice.

The first time you execute the insert is at `$result_i = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i );` and you store the result of that insert into the variable $result_i.

Now instead of checking the result of that insert (which is stored in $result_i), you run the insert again and check that result at `if ( $result_i ) {`.

You see, instead of checking the result of the first insert, you check the result of the second insert.

Answer (score 0):

There're no loops in your code. You just execute your `INSERT` query twice:

```
// query executed first time, record added
$result_i = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i );   

// query executed second time, record added again
if ( mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i ) ) { //  <----This was my bug
```

So, indeed solution can be either:

```
// query executed first time, record added
$result_i = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i );

// NO second query here
if ( $result_i ) {
    redirect_to( "profile_image_fetch_image.php?id=$S_id" );
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql_i . "<br>" . mysqli_error( $conn );
}
```

Or:

```
// $result_i = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i );  // remove this line

// query executed first time, record added, NO more queries here
if ( mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_i ) ) {
    redirect_to( "profile_image_fetch_image.php?id=$S_id" );
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql_i . "<br>" . mysqli_error( $conn );
}
```